# Azure app service - web deployment using FTP

Tags: azure, azure-cli

For web deployment using FTP;I came across a situation, where i'm using Azure CLI command to create an app service plan in FREE tier to deploy the web app in it.

Here is how i am approaching:

1. used command:

   az login --allow-no-subscriptions

sign in, use a web browser to open the page https://microsoft.com/devicelogin and enter the code xxxxxxx to authenticate. Working fine with below result.

```
      [
   {
     "cloudName": "AzureCloud",
    "id": "1fdacf7a-xxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "isDefault": true,
    "name": "N/A(tenant level account)",
    "state": "Enabled",
    "tenantId": "1fdacf7a-xxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxx",
     "user": {
      "name": "email@gmail.com",
      "type": "user"
    }
   }
 ]
```

2. Then, create basic app service plan using :

   "az appservice plan create -g MyResourceGroup -n MyPlan"

   This gives me error saying "The subscription 1fdacf7a-xxxxx-xxxx-xxxx- 
     xxxxxxxxxxxxx could not be found.

How to resolve this problem? Thanks.

Comment: Make sure you have the owner role like this [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2rxkl.png).

Comment: Hi, if my reply is helpful, please accept it, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I can reproduce your issue, to fix the issue, please don't use the `--allow-no-subscriptions` parameter.

[image]

You just need to login with:

```
az login
```

or

```
az login --use-device-code
```

Then use the command below to set the subscription:

```
az account set --subscription 1fdacf7a-xxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Run `az appservice plan create -g MyResourceGroup -n MyPlan`:

[image]